# Need to use a different font for PHP Captcha image

Tags: php, fonts, captcha

I've got quite a solid PHP form (in terms of preventing spam) that I've been using for years now however I want to change the font for which the captcha uses because quite often people can't distinguish between the numerical '0' and the uppercase letter 'O' and then they think my form "doesn't work" and I get a complaint. I'm not sure what font it's currently using - see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HJrp.jpg).

But I'd like to change it to a font that's more readable like "Times New Roman", Times or serif.

Here is my php code to generate captcha image:

```
    <?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start(); header("(anti-
spam-content-type:) image/png");

    $enc_num = rand(0, 9999);
    $key_num = rand(0, 24);
    $hash_string = substr(md5($enc_num), $key_num, 5); // Length of 
String
    $hash_md5 = md5($hash_string);

    $_SESSION['verify'] = $hash_md5;

    // Fallback
    setcookie("verify", $hash_md5, time()+3600, "/");

    session_write_close();

    // Verification Image Background Selection

    $bgs = array("img/1.png","img/2.png","img/3.png");
    $background = array_rand($bgs, 1);

    // Verification Image Variables

    $img_handle = imagecreatefrompng($bgs[$background]);
    $text_colour = imagecolorallocate($img_handle, 108, 127, 6);
    $font_size = 5;

    $size_array = getimagesize($bgs[$background]);
    $img_w = $size_array[0];
    $img_h = $size_array[1];

    $horiz = round(($img_w/2)-
((strlen($hash_string)*imagefontwidth(5))/2), 1);
    $vert = round(($img_h/2)-(imagefontheight($font_size)/2));

    // Make the Verification Image

    imagestring($img_handle, $font_size, $horiz, $vert, $hash_string, 
$text_colour);
    imagepng($img_handle);

    // Destroy the Image to keep Server Space

    imagedestroy($img_handle);

    ?>
```

I did do some research on this the other day but cannot find those posts again.

I did try adding **$font** within imagestring like so:

```
imagestring($img_handle, $font, $font_size, $horiz, $vert, 
$hash_string,
```

and then a variable:

**$font = 'serif';**

But the captcha doesn't generate.

What am I doing wrong? I just want the font to be in serif format.
Is there a simple way to declare a font type (serif) to this captcha without hosting a font file or pointing it to the users PC's font location (eg: C:\Windows\Fonts\serif.ttf ... reason why not for the latter is because what happens if someone uses their android smartphone then the location C:\Windows\Fonts\serif.ttf won't work).

Comment: "But I'd like to change it to a font that's more readable like "Times New Roman", Times or serif." Ditch the captcha, then. The entire point of a captcha is to be difficult for a computer to read, hence the weird fonts. Or, switch to ReCaptcha.

Comment: The captcha shown in your screenshot is unlikely to be effective since the text is so easy to read. Why not use something like [Google's reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) instead?

Comment: @ceejayoz ... so you telling me that if it's more readable to the human eye, that means it's more vulnerable to spam? Does the same apply if I made the captcha image bigger? If so it would be good to test the difference to see if I receive more (or any) spam

Comment: @Chris ... I've thought about that but I know (with my limited knowledge) that I will probably struggle to incorporate it into my current form setup. Maybe not ... but in the meantime I'd like to just stick with this captcha and then with time I will try work on the google reCAPTCHA

Comment: @user3364730, then you might as well just scrap this CAPTCHA. It's virtually useless. I imagine not having to fill it in at all will reduce your CAPTCHA-related complaints :-).

Comment: @Chris ... oh and I've yet to receive a spam submission from this form (and I'm talking about hundreds of these forms used out there over probably 6 years)

Comment: @user3364730, I hate to burst your bubble, but that's probably because your forms aren't worth spamming more so than because you have an effective CAPTCHA. How many form submissions that have failed because of the CAPTCHA do you believe to truly be spam attempts?

Comment: @Chris ... "It's virtually useless" in terms of preventing spam it's been the best (hence why I'm adamant to stick by it) ... my main concern was to make it a bit more readable for submitters by changing the font. If changing the font does make spamming more vulnerable, then I couldn't give a damn if they cannot distinguish between "0" and "O" with current font

Comment: @Chris ... "How many form submissions that have failed because of the CAPTCHA do you believe to truly be spam attempts" ...I would never know but at the moment I'm more concerned about a legit person failing to fill the correct verification code in because then they think somethings wrong. Understand that I'm not concerned at all about spam because I don't get any (even if my forms aren't "worth" spamming)... and I'm not trying to sound arrogant here, my initial question was about adding a different font type like a serif.

Answer (score 1):

The [`imagestring()`](http://php.net/imagestring) function is not capable of using TTF fonts.

If you want to use that Serif TTF font, you'll need to switch over and use [`imagettftext()`](http://php.net/imagettftext) function which requires that your PHP install be built with FreeType support.

You also do realize that because you're using md5 to build your captcha code, it won't be able to have the O (oh) character in it because md5 will return a string consisting of `[0-9a-f]`?  They're probably mistaking a zero for an O when it can't actually contain an O.

You should build the letters from a character set that excludes indistinguishable characters (1, l, I, 0, O, etc).

```
$charset = 'abcdefghkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789';
```

Comment: Much appreciate your help! You make some interesting points! Your suggestion of building a charset makes sense and I take it it is the easiest solution (for me at least)... I tried adding `$charset = 'abcdefghkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789';` to my code but the excluded characters are still generating in my captcha. I take it's not a case of simply adding this variable in my code above correct? Anything else I need to do in addition?

Comment: Yes, you then have to write a few lines of code to pick a number of random characters from the set and build the captcha string and then replace $hash_string with the randomly generated one.